# Can I get an explanation on how to access a sprite in my scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So In my unity hierarchy, I have a sprite named `Bet1Select` and I want to make a script to move it around in my scene.

Here is what I got in my new script can someone help me out?

```
public class Bet1Select : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    Sprite redBar;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // some code here
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // some code here           
    }


    private void MoveRedBar()
    {
        // I'm trying to find the sprite Bet1Select but,
        // it says that the type name Bet1Select does not exist in Sprite  
        FindObjectOfType<Sprite.Bet1Select>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `Bet1Select` script as a component of your "Bet1Select" sprite. You can do this by selecting your object, and then dragging the script in the inspector view or by clicking the button "Add Component". Finally, you can use the method `GetComponent<T>()` in your script to get a reference of your components and manipulate their values, such as the object position.

Therefore, there is an easier and convenient way to access your object than make use of `FindObjectTypeOf<T>()`. I don't know how exactly you intended to use it, but don't let it to be called frame by frame, because it's very slow.

You can get further information and guidance from the following resources:

- [Scripting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html)
- [Components](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ControllingGameObjectsComponents.html)
- [Object.FindObjectOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html)